# How to unittest with command line arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am using the python unittest module for testing a file that takes a command line argument. The argument is a file name which is then passed into a function like so:

```
file_name = str(sys.argv[1])
file = open(file_name)
result = main_loop(file)
print(result)
```

My test is set up like so:

```
class testMainFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main_loop(self):
        file = open('file_name.json')
        result = main_file.main_loop(file)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Expected Result')
                
if __name__ == 'main':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test I get an "IndexError: list index out of range".

I tried passing the argument when running the test but to no avail. How do I run my test without error?

Comment: You can assign directly to `sys.argv`, but it's not clear how you are importing your script for testing. There's a lot of apparent duplication between your script and the test code, and no mention of where `main_file` is defined.

Comment: Can you explain further on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have couple of options here. Firstly go to documentation and checkout [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) because i think you can get away with

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('sys.argv', ['mock.py', 'test-value'])
def test_main_loop(self):
```

---

*Options for fun:*

**One** would be simply to override the `sys.argv` next to your call

```
def test_main_loop(self):
    file = open('file_name.json')
+   orginal_argv = sys.argv
+   sys.argv = ['mock argv', 'my-test-value'] 
    result = main_file.main_loop(file)
+   sys.argv = orginal_argv 
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Expected Result')
```

**Second** would be to create a simple wrapper for your function

```
def set_sys_argv(func: Callable):
    sys.argv = ['mock.py', 'my_test_value']
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func()
    return wrapper
```

and use it with test function

```
@set_sys_argv
def test_main_loop(self):
```

We can improve it slightly and make it more generic making a decorator that accepts the values to mock

```
def set_sys_argv(*argv):
    sys.argv = argv

    def _decorator(func: Callable):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func()
        return wrapper
    return _decorator
```

and use it similarly to patch

```
@set_sys_argv('mock.py', 'test-value')
def test_main_loop(self):
```

**Third** would be to create a context manager, likewise:

```
class ReplaceSysArgv(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._argv = sys.argv
        sys.argv = ['mock', 'my-test-value']
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        sys.argv = self._argv
```

and use it with your code

```
    def test_main_loop(self):
        file = open('file_name.json')
        with ReplaceSysArgv():
            result = main_file.main_loop(file)
        self.assertEqual(result, 'Expected Result')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to push the arguments onto sys.argv before retrieving them (if your code is pulling from command-line arguments - it's unclear to me where in your test you're using the command-line arguments but I digress)

so something like first doing

```py
import sys

sys.argv = ['mock_filename.py', 'json_file.json']
#... continue with rest of program / test.
```

Comment: Sorry I am a little unclear what I do with the sys.argv list after defining it.